# Prevent body overlapping footer in mPDF

Tags: php, mpdf

I'm generating PDFs using mPDF library, and my header and footer vary in size depending on a couple of parameters.

A static solution would be to set the footer margin, which will solve the overlapping - but as the footer may vary in size this is not a solution I feel happy with. Is there a way to get the footer dimensions and apply the margin accordingly?

Comment: I'm having the same problem atm, if you found a solution to it can you please update your question?

Comment: I've updated my answer below. Hopefully it will help you. Document margins have to be set for margin_header/footer. You might also need to disable the `setAutoTopMargin` setting in your config file.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem lies in the documentation of mpdf. I think margin_footer and margin_header is the margin between the document body and these. Instead, margin_footer and margin_header is the document margins, as one would think margin_top and margin_bottom would be.

So, changing the bottom and top margin will decide where the document body starts. And changing the header/footer margin will decide the printing margins.

Hope it helps!

**Updated answer**

mPDF documentation is a bit off for the constructor call, I guess. The margin_top/bottom argument is actually the content margin, and does not apply for margin_header/footer arguments. (If I recall correctly). The margin_top/bottom is the absolute margin from the top of the document, and should include the height of the header/footer.

Here is the correct way of handling the margins:

```
/**
 * Create a new PDF document
 *
 * @param string $mode
 * @param string $format
 * @param int $font_size
 * @param string $font
 * @param int $margin_left
 * @param int $margin_right
 * @param int $margin_top (Margin between content and header, not to be mixed with margin_header - which is document margin)
 * @param int $margin_bottom (Margin between content and footer, not to be mixed with margin_footer - which is document margin)
 * @param int $margin_header
 * @param int $margin_footer
 * @param string $orientation (P, L)
 */
new mPDF($mode, $format, $font_size, $font, $margin_left, $margin_right, $margin_top, $margin_bottom, $margin_header, $margin_footer, $orientation);
```

Comment: thanks for the update, also the "experimental settings" `$mpdf->setAutoTopMargin = 'stretch' and $mpdf->setAutoBottomMargin = 'stretch'` settings will make sure the header and footer never overlap the main body, without you having to manually compute the header and footer margins. Quite useful when dealing with dynamic, user-created headers and footers

Comment: Woah! Didn't know that was possible. Thank you for that information, it will come in handy very soon.

Comment: I tried $mpdf->setAutoBottomMargin = 'stretch' with no success, any instructions how to use it please?

Comment: $mpdf->setAutoBottomMargin = 'stretch'; worked for us

Answer (score 23):

```
$mpdf->setAutoBottomMargin = 'stretch';
```

Worked for me. All I had to do was to make sure I included the option before the footer.

Comment: It didn't work for me as well until I set it before the footer.

Comment: You can use `->setAutoTopMargin()` for headers.

Comment: Its working..I'm using footer by `<htmlpagefooter>`. `$mpdf->setAutoBottomMargin = 'stretch';` it solved the overlap problem.

Answer (score 7):

It didn't worked for me, but I've managed to find how to solve this. All I had to do was to **set the footer before any content**. This is because the footer's height calculation is done before any content processing. But if you add a footer later with `SetHTMLFooter`, mPDF don't recalculate the footer's height, so it will be 0. This way there will be no page break and the content will overlap the body. So the final solution was:

1. Create the mPDF object with `'setAutoBottomMargin' => 'stretch'`
2. Add the header
3. Add the footer
4. Add the content

Hope it helps.

Comment: love you mate, fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
'setAutoBottomMargin' => 'stretch'
```

That's attribute works for me.

Here is my code

```php
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
  'setAutoBottomMargin' => 'stretch'
]);
```